# Apache beam/Google dataflow enrich upstream records with downstream aggregates

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a Java apache beam stream pipeline that I plan to run on google dataflow. It receives elements that look similar to the following:

```
ipAddress, serviceUsed, errorOrSuccess, time, parameter, etc.
```

for example

```
'237.98.58.248', 'service1', 'error', '12345', 'randomParameter', etc
```

I currently window this data into fixed windows based on the event time. I would like to use my pipeline to calculate the number of errors and success each ip address received on a per window basis, and then enrich the original data.

I am hoping to adjust each original element to output final elements similar to the following:

```
totalErrorsInThisWindow, totalSuccessInThisWindow, ipAddress, serviceUsed, errorOrSuccess, time, parameter, etc.
```

for example

```
'237.98.58.248', 'service1', 'error', '12345', 'randomParameter', etc
'149.142.114.250', 'service2', 'success', '12346', 'randomParameter', etc
'237.98.58.248', 'service3', 'error', '12344', 'randomParameter', etc
...
```

Becomes something like

```
'100', '1000', '237.98.58.248', 'service1', 'error', '12345', 'randomParameter', etc
'11', '34', '149.142.114.250', 'service2', 'success', '12346', 'randomParameter', etc
'100', '1000', '237.98.58.248', 'service3', 'error', '12344', 'randomParameter', etc
...
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

I know a few ways how to calculate the `totalErrorsInThisWindow` and `totalSuccessInThisWindow` on a per client, per window basis - one way would be to drop all the columns except the `ipAddress` and `errorOrSuccess` and then perform an `apply(Count.<String>perElement());`. However I am struggling to then enrich the original data. First thought's would be to use a side input, but I don't think it will work well to have a constantly changing side input.

The other option is to maintain a key based state variable for success and failure, which I can increment as I process each element and use to enrich the data in the very same DoFn. However, I then have the problem where only the last elements to be processed in the window for each key will have the correct success and failure values.

Here is an example of what I can do with state vs what I want to do with state:

Input:

```
'a'
'b'
'a'
'a'
```

Output I can get using state:

```
'a':1
'b':1
'a':2
'a':3
```

Output I want to get using state:

```
'a':3
'b':1
'a':3
'a':3
```

I hope my question is clear, and I hope my current approaches and challenges are also clear. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at GroupByKey and Combiners, and [how to use it with windowing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing).

I think something like this would work well. You can group by IP, apply the window and count the errors and successes.

```
PCollection<MyRecord> records = <Read from your source>

PCollection<KV<string, MyRecord>> withIP = records.apply(ParDo.of(
    new DoFn<MyRecord, KV<KV<string, MyRecord>>>() {
      // Implement processElement and call outputWithTimestamp
    }
));


PCollection<MyRecord> windowed = withIP.apply(
    Window.<MyRecord>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(60))));

PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<MyRecords>>> grouped = 
    windowed.apply(GroupByKey.<String, MyRecords>create());


PCollection<KV<String, MyErrorStats>> errorsPerIP =
  playerAccuracy.apply(Combine.<String, MyRecord, MyErrorStats>perKey(
    new MyErrorStatsCombiner())));


public static class MyErrorStatsCombiner implements     
SerializableFunction<Iterable<MyRecords>, MyErrorStats> {
  @Override
  public Integer apply(Iterable<MyRecords> record) {
    MyErrorStats stats = new MyErrorStats();
    for (int item : record) {
      stats.errorsInThisWindow += item.errorsInThisWindow;
      stats.successInThisWindow += item.successInThisWindow;
    }
    return stats;
  }
}
```

As for preserving the other metadata fields in the records, you can decide how to aggregate/preserve those as well in the MyErrorStatsCombiner.

It's not clear to me if you really want to just group by the IP or group by multiple different metadata fields. If you want to group by multiple metadata fields and get counts for all of those then. This might be a useful reference. [GroupBy using multiple data properties](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-2). You may be able to first group by IP and whether or not it is a success or error. Though, I think you would not be able to get the  output you want with the total errors and successes in the same record. You might be able to complete that last part easily with a bigquery query for example.